# How to use Realm SDK with vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, realm, vuejs3

i have use realm sdk in vue2 with this syntax

```
// file scr/plugins/realm.js

import Vue from 'vue';
import {App} from 'realm-web';
Vue.prototype.realmApp = new App({id: 'artes-realm-vl12'})

//file scr/main.js
import './plugins/realm';
```

but in Vue3 this syntax is't working anymore can you please help me how to solve with this problem thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main.js` add that app as global property :

```
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import {App} from 'realm-web';

import app from './App.vue'

const myApp=createApp(app)

myApp.config.globalProperties.realmApp = new App({id: 'artes-realm-vl12'})

myApp.mount('#app');
```

Comment: it's confict with App from App.vue

Comment: import the component with lowercase format `import app from './App.vue'`